# Return iNode usage in Solaris

Tags: shell, solaris, inode

I am working to create a shell script to return iNode usage from a Solaris box.

The command I use to run is: `df -F ufs -o i`,

and say the output is:

```
    Filesystem             iused   ifree  %iused  Mounted on
    /dev/dsk/c1t0d0s1     248503 3443913     7%   /
```

The only part I need to catch is 7%. Please help me on the part that returns the %iused, and output it at the end of the script.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Madean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df -F ufs -o i | nawk 'NR>1 {print $4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set `df -F ufs -o i`
printf '%s\n' ${10}
```

This works as long as the `df` output is exactly as you've shown. If it actually has more lines and you are only interested in the root file system /, then use `df ... /` to make it output only the stats you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
df -F ufs -o i | sed -n '$p' | awk '{print $4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

`df -F ufs -o i | grep ^/ | awk '{print $4}'`